# Factorization problem in Cyclic cubic field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let K/$\mathbb{Q}$ be a cubic number field.  Assume that K/Q be Galois with class number 1.

Therefore Gal(K/Q) is cyclic cubic group and $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID.

Let p be a rational prime, p doesn't divide disc(K).  Then p is splits completely or inert in K.

Consider the unit group $\mathcal{O}_K^*$. Does there exists a unit $\epsilon$ in $\mathcal{O}_K^*$ such that $(\pi)$ | $(\epsilon -1)$ but $(\pi^2)$ does not divide $(\epsilon -1)$  where $\pi$ is a unramified prime over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1691625/factorization-problem-in-cyclic-cubic-field